# Efficiently implementing DXT1 texture decompression in hardware

Tags: gpu, vhdl, texture-mapping, hdl, dxt

[DXT1 compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S3_Texture_Compression) is designed to be fast to decompress in hardware where its used in texture samplers. The Wikipedia article says that under certain circumstances you can work out the co-efficients of the interpolated colours as:

```
c2 = (2/3)*c0+(1/3)*c1
```

or rearranging that:

```
c2 = (1/3)*(2*c0+c1)
```

However you re-arrange the above equation, then you end up always having to multiply something by 1/3 (or dividing by 3, same deal even more expensive). And it seems weird to me that a texture format which is designed to be fast to decompress in hardware would require a multiplication or division. The FPGA I'm implementing my GPU on only has limited resources for multiplications and I want to save those for where they're really required.

So am I missing something? Is there an efficient way of avoiding the multiplications of the colour channels by a 1/3? Or should I just eat the cost of that multiplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a bad way of imagining it, but could you implement it via the use of addition/subtraction of successive halves (shifts)?

As you have 16 bits this gives you the ability to get quite accurate with successive additions and subtractions.

A third could be represented as

a(n+1) = a(n) +/- A>>1, where, the list [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, etc] shows whether to add or subtract the shifted result.

I believe this is called fractional maths.

However, in FPGAs, it is difficult to know whether this is actually more power efficient than the native DSP blocks (e.g. DSP48E1) provided.

Comment: I'm beginning to think this is (both our ways) a good way of doing it. I misread the documentation and although you do the compare as a 16bit integer you do the interpolate (with the 1/3 co-efficients) separately for each colour. That means the maximum size of the value is 6 bits [0-63]. So if I'm careful I could probably get either full accuracy or maybe +/-1 of the required result like this. As for not using the DSPs for me its not power, its just the number of them is limited and I want to have as many simultaneous tiles rendering as possible and DSPs is my limiting factor for that.

Comment: (this is a fun home project GPU I'm making so I can choose to ignore power - https://mikevine.net/)

Answer (score 1):

MY best answer I can come up with is that I can use the identity:

```
x/3 = sum(n=1 to infinity) (x/2^(2n))
```

and then take the first n terms. Using 4 terms I get:

```
(x/4)+(x/16)+(x/64)+(x/256)
```

which equals

```
x*0.33203125
```

which is probably good enough.

This relies on multiplication by a fixed power of 2 being free in hardware, then 3 additions of which I can run 2 in parallel.

Any better answer is appreciated though.

** EDIT **: Using a combination of this and @dyslexicgruffalo's answer I made a simple c++ program which iterated over the various sequences and tried them all and recorded the various average/max errors.

I did this for 0 <= x <= 189 (as 189 is the value of 2*c0.g + c1.g when g (which is 6 bits) maxes out.

The shortest good sequence (with a max error of 2, average error of 0.62) and is 4 ops was:

```
1 + x/4 + x/16 + x/64.
```

The best sequence which had a max error of 1, average error of 0.32, but is 6 ops was:

```
x/2 - x/4 + x/8 - x/16 + x/32 - x/64.
```

For the 5 bit values (red and blue) the maximum value is 31*3 and the above sequences are still good but not the best. These are:

```
x/4 + x/8 - x/16 + x/32 [max error of 1, average 0.38]
```

and

```
1 + x/4 + x/16 [max error of 2, average of 0.68]
```

(And, luckily, none of the above sequences ever guesses an answer which is too big so no clamping is needed even though they're not perfect)

Comment: Apologies @Mike Vine, I think we have written the same answer of sorts!